# Unable to write values into excel using multiple workbook.write methods

Tags: java, eclipse

The below code is working without any runtime error if I call the `owb.write(fileOut)` and `fileOut.close()` method only once at at the ending (commented as `write and close positioning`) but the problem here is that the first value to be set when `k=1`, is not being printed in the workbook. It works fine when the iteration is in other columns and `k=1`.Only the first iteration is not being printed. Rest of the values are being set correctly.

I tried using multiple `workbook.write()` method. If you look at the below code, commented as `[1]`, I had to invoke `owb.write(fileOut)` separately in the `if` condition(commented as `if condition[1]`) and `else` condition(commented as `else condition [2]`) because as I said, first value was not getting set in the workbook. I am getting the following runtime error while trying to execute the code in this scenario: 
 *Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@3740f768*

```js
       for(int i=0;i<noOfCols1;i++)
        {
         for(int j=1;j<=noOfRows1;j++)
         {
          value1 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(i));
           for(int m=1;m<=noOfRows2;m++)
           {
            value2 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet2.getRow(m).getCell(i));
            value1= value1.trim();
            value2=value2.trim();
            int value2Position = sheet2.getRow(m).getCell(i).getRowIndex();
            if(!positions.contains(value2Position))
            {
             if(value1.contentEquals(value2))
             {
             positions.add(value2Position);
             matched = true;
             }
             else{
              matched = false;
             }
            }
            if(matched==true)
            {
             break;
            }
           }
           if(matched == false)
           {   
            int k=1;
            if(cFilledPositions.isEmpty())   //If condition[i]
            {
             rowHead =  sheet.createRow((short)k);
                rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
                owb.write(fileOut);   //[1]
            }
            else     //else condition [1]
            {
             int l = cFilledPositions.size()-1; 
              k = cFilledPositions.get(l)+1;
              rowHead =  sheet.createRow((short)k);
                    rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
                    owb.write(fileOut);
            }
            cFilledPositions.add(k); 
               }
           matched = false;
         }
         cFilledPositions.clear();
         positions.clear(); 
        }
               //write and close positioning
        fileOut.close();
```

Comment: You do know that each `workbook.write()` actually writes the file to the disk? So multiple writes could cause you to overwrite data. This could make you think that its not working because you overwrite the stuff you want

Comment: Hi @XtremeBaumer. Thank you for your prompt reply. I did not know that. Will try to find a work around for that. But as I mentioned in my question, the first value that is to be written to the workbook, is not being printed.

Comment: Because you probably overwrite it. Check if it still happens if you have only 1 `workbook.write()`

Comment: Yes the problem of the first value not being set arises only when is use the write and close function at the end of the program, outside all the loops.

Comment: Hi @XtremeBaumer. I got the solution. I tried debugging, and found that the sheet.createRow() deletes the values created previously if called again for the same row. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried debugging and found that the createRow() method deletes the values previously created  if called again on the same row.

To elaborate this, suppose the sheet.createRow() sets the value of a cell in the first iteration, and when it finishes its iteration in the `j` `for` loop, the `cFilledPositions` list is cleared and while it comes back after going to the main loop, 'cFilledPositions`will be empty and the integer`k`will again be initialized to`1`. This is when`createRow(k)` which is 1 is called again. This would flush out the previously existing values in the 1st row. I am trying to figure out a work around for this and will edit my answer with the solution if I my code works.

Below was the work around. I checked if the row is empty. The createRow function is called only when the row is empty. I have added the comments for the new code.

```js
 for(int i=0;i<noOfCols1;i++)
        {
         for(int j=1;j<=noOfRows1;j++)
         {
          value1 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(i));
           for(int m=1;m<=noOfRows2;m++)
           {
            value2 = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet2.getRow(m).getCell(i));
            value1= value1.trim();
            value2=value2.trim();
            int value2Position = sheet2.getRow(m).getCell(i).getRowIndex();
            if(!positions.contains(value2Position))
            {
             if(value1.contentEquals(value2))
             {
             positions.add(value2Position);
             matched = true;
             }
             else{
              matched = false;
             }
            }
            if(matched==true)
            {
             break;
            }
           }
           if(matched == false)
           {   
            int k=1;
                        
            if(cFilledPositions.isEmpty())
            {
             try{
             isEmpty = checkIfRowIsEmpty(sheet,k,formatter);
             if(isEmpty)
             {
              rowHead = sheet.createRow(k);
             }
                           rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
             }
             catch (Exception e){
              try{
               rowHead = sheet.createRow(k);
                rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
              }
              catch (Exception e1){
               
              }
             }
                
            }
            else
            {
             int l = cFilledPositions.size()-1;
              k = cFilledPositions.get(l)+1;
              try{
                     isEmpty = checkIfRowIsEmpty(sheet,k,formatter);
                     if(isEmpty)
                     {
                      rowHead =  sheet.createRow(k);
                     }
                    rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
               try{
                   rowHead = sheet.createRow(k);
                    rowHead.createCell(i).setCellValue(value1);
                  }
                  catch (Exception e1){
                   
                  }
              }
            }
            cFilledPositions.add(k); 
               }
           matched = false;
         }
         cFilledPositions.clear();
         positions.clear(); 
        }
```